# How to put the page title in a url pattern with Django?

Tags: django, url, django-urls

If I wanted to send the blogpost id to the url pattern, and have the url automatically turn into something like `www.blog.com/post/2/this-is-my-second-blogpost`, how might I do that?

Inside of urls.py I have a url pattern that accepts the blogpost id, and its title. It doesn't seem to be working, and once it does, would be tedious to add the title for every page in this manner.

urls.py:`path('post/<int:post_id>/<str:post_title>', views.view_post, name='view_post'),`

blogposts.html template:
`<a href="{% url 'blogs:view_post' post.id post.title%}">Read More</a>`

views.py: `def view_post(request, post_id, post_title):`.

Comment: you don't need title in the url. What's the purpose?

Comment: so if the link is shared, users can read the title before they click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use a `slug` field for the url instead of the combination of id and title, your url will look like `example.org/title-to-object-2/`.
Now you have a unique slug field with the title and the id.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, add the default argument of `post_title` to be `None`. If you are wishing to get the `post_title` directly from the `post_id`, neclect the `post_title`, doing this won't give you error as functions already got all the satisfied argument values.

So:

```
def view_post(request, post_id, post_title=None):
```

### Edit

Okay, what user wanted was about `slug field`. Slug field is the field type in django model. Basically, it is used for the url type. In above problem, what *pyknight202* wanted was the url patter for the `post_title`. So, you could not use tilte directly as url as they contain spaces, so for that you have to add `post_title` in hyphens or underscore to be readable. Therefore, you need slug field in `Post` model.

```
https://helloworld.com/1/this-is-example
```

So, 1 is `post_id` as slug could not be unique, so you could not only retrieve from `post_title` therefore you need `post_id` too. [Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: would it be possible to send only the id and have the url use that to add the post_title to the end?

Comment: a template sends the user and post_id to a new url pattern, which by using the id to get the post object, concatenates the post_title to the end of the url

Comment: Yes that's possible absolutely.... If you can retrieve ```post_title``` from ```post_id```, then you don't have to add that to parameter...

Comment: could you explain how I could do that without sending post_title to the view? my attempts have returned ```view_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_title'```. It seems post_title=None would be changed once post_title is sent to the view.

Comment: well, i missunderstood what you said before... you want to add title url at the end, that's possible but you have to redirect it to another similar url..which i think is not good solution.

Comment: I found a solution different from the one we were proposing, however it was deleted by a moderator. I think it would be beneficial to those that come across this problem to see a solution. Slugs are a field type for models, one created for this purpose. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Comment: I have edited from your comment, so let me know if it is what you wanted. !!! Thank you ...